# Is there any properties or anything in SSIS that will not allow users to open a excel file?

Tags: ssis

We have a SSIS package that creates an excel file from OLE DB source. The excel file is created as expected in a folder but the users cannot open a file. They can see the file but not able to open it. The permission is granted but still not able to open the file.

Anyone has face this issue before?

I went over the package but not able to find anything that may have caused this. I made sure that the users are granted the right permission.

Comment: Can they copy the file from the network location to their desktop and then open it? When you say they "cannot open" the file, what does that actually mean? What error is reported? As a developer, can you reproduce the error?  When you say "the permission is granted" _what_ permission(s) are granted, _how_ have they been granted and to _whom_ have they been granted?